# Jquery toggleClass problem

Tags: jquery, mouseover, effect, toggleclass

please help me with my Jquery toggleClass menu.

It works properly, only if you stay on button more than 200ms, otherwise it fails.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.menu { width: 200px; padding: 5px; margin:10px 0;border:1px solid #FF0000;background: #FFFF00; color: #FF0000;display:block;}
.menu_over { width: 200px; padding: 5px; margin:10px 0; border:1px solid #000000;background: #FF0000; color: #ffffff;display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#menu_left a.menu").hover(
        function() {
             $(this).toggleClass( "menu_over", 200 );
        }
    ),
        function() {
             $(this).toggleClass( "menu", 200 );
        }
});
</script>
<div id="menu_left">
    <a href="#" class="menu">AFRICA</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">AMERICA</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">ANTARCTICA</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">ASIA</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">AUSTRALIA</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu">EUROPE</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice solution Dutchie. A simple solution to this problem would be to stop the animation/fx queue. It'll mean you can continue to animate by toggling class.

```
var toggle = function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).toggleClass( "menu_over", 200);
};

$("#menu_left a.menu").hover(toggle, toggle);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NBdR5/10/

Comment: WOW, and this is really what i was looking for, for about 2 days  :)
Thankx, Gary!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why the fade is giving you those problems, but there are two problems I see with your code.

1) The main problem is that your `.hover` function is malformed.

The correct format is

```
$(item).hover(
   function(){}, //Actions on Mouseover
   function(){} //Actions on Mouseout
);
```

2) You're toggling one class on `mouseover`, and toggling a different class on `mouseout`. This is going to cause some odd results.

See my [DEMO Without Fades](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/NBdR5/) for further illustration. Also, note my reduced/simplified CSS.

Your code should look similar to this

```
$("#menu_left a.menu").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "menu_over");
},function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "menu_over");
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep the fades, use `animate()` ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/NBdR5/7/))

```
$("#menu_left a.menu").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-color': '#ff0000',
        'color' : '#ffffff',   
        'border-color' : '#000000'       
    }, 200);
},function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'background-color': '#ffff00',
        'color' : '#ff0000',   
        'border-color' : '#ff0000'       
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: But the one and only thing i need are the Fades :)

Comment: Okay, then see update. (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/NBdR5/7/). The correct way to do this is via the `animate()` function.

Comment: Wow great, it works, and also without JqueryUI.
Thank you very much!